# ArrayAdaptor constructor not being found

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am working to display a list of all devices that have been connected to an Android phone. I would really like to keep using the fragments to help with easy navigation. I am getting an error on the ArrayAdapter adapter1 code that states `Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.henryjarend.test.Connect2, int, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'`

I have looked at the constructor on the android developer APIs and it seems like it should be working.

Here is the code:

```
public class Connect2 extends ListFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.connect2, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    List<String> previousDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices){
        previousDevices.add(bt.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.connect2, previousDevices);

    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.list, previousDevices));
    }
}
```

the commented out section was another example I had found online but it had the same issue that the uncommented one is having.

Comment: Change `this` to `getActivity()`. In that code, `this` refers to the `ListFragment`, which is not a `Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem :**

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = 
                     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.connect2, previousDevices)
```

`this` here is a `ListFragment`, get activity of this fragment for the context.

**Solution :**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.connect2, previousDevices)
```